# Something is injecting a slash after any static file response , server is nginx

Tags: nginx

This is what chrome's console says:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "someserver/wp-content/themes/pgcss/normalize.css/?ver=3.5.1". someserver:18
>
> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "someserver/wp-content/themes/pgimg/lens.png/". someserver:77

Obviously something in injecting a slash at the end of my file.
I am not very familiar with nginx , what can I do?

Comment: Can you supply the code that enqueues the stylesheet and that outputs the image?

Comment: What is your Nginx configuration for rewrites? Are you using `try_files`? Please paste your site config in the original question so we can see the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Check the mime.types file in Nginx's config directory (if you're on Linux this is typically /etc/nginx/).  If there's no MIME type file, check to see whether MIME types are declared inside nginx.conf.  If not, you may need to create a mime.types file and include it in nginx.conf.

Here's the information on the Nginx wiki about MIME types: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#types